# Mid-flow file sourcing with Spring Integration DSL

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm in the need to create a flow that, whenever a file is received at a folder, it picks up some other pre-existing files from a different folder, transforms all of them (including the newly received) using the same `transformer` and then aggregates them to create a single output. 
I imagine I could use a `splitter`-`aggregator` approach to do the transformation and aggregation steps; but I don't know what SI component type (if any) I could use to merge the new file (the one that's received from the original `MessageSource` that kicks-off the flow execution) with the existing ones in a same flow.

The project I'm working on uses `spring-integration-core-5.0.11.RELEASE` and `spring-integration-file-5.0.11.RELEASE` and we're creating the flows using Spring Integration DSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, consider to use a. `.enrich()` EIP-method:

```
/**
 * Populate a {@link org.springframework.integration.transformer.ContentEnricher}
 * to the current integration flow position
 * with provided options.
 * Typically used with a Java 8 Lambda expression:
 * <pre class="code">
 * {@code
 *  .enrich(e -> e.requestChannel("enrichChannel")
 *                  .requestPayload(Message::getPayload)
 *                  .shouldClonePayload(false)
 *                  .autoStartup(false)
 *                  .<Map<String, String>>headerFunction("foo", m -> m.getPayload().get("name")))
 * }
 * </pre>
 * @param enricherConfigurer the {@link Consumer} to provide
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.transformer.ContentEnricher} options.
 * @return the current {@link IntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 * @see EnricherSpec
 */
public B enrich(Consumer<EnricherSpec> enricherConfigurer) {
```

This way you can call whatever you need based on the request messages and store everything in the output payload.

Please, see more info about `Enricher` in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#payload-enricher).

Also you can take a look into the [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/enricher). I know that one is on XML config, but the principle is the same.

**UPDATE**

For that trick you need to wrap your request `File` into `Collection` (`List`, of course) and all the other file you'd just add to this collection with a simple `addAll()` expression.

Another, much better solution would be with the `.gateway()`. So, you send your file over there and simply return a `Collection` together with others. This way your flow should be smooth enough to just deal with one file upstream and collection downstream.

Comment: Thanks, Artem. I have two questions regarding this: 
1. Is it considered idiomatic to use `.enrich` to change the payload type? (as the input to `.enrich` would be a `File` and the output would be `Collection<File>`)

Comment: Well, you can wrap a request file into a `Collection` before calling that `enrich()`, but yeah: I agree that this is not a perfect solution. I will edit my answer soon...

Comment: Thanks! That's much clearer. My last question was: should I do the multiple-file-sourcing by myself on a bean, or there's a way to plug a `Files.inboundAdapter` that handles multiple files in the gateway itself? Because the reference I've found is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787650/file-inbound-channel-adapter-spring-integration-for-multiple-files-aggregation-i) but seems pretty outdated.

Comment: Well, I think that is fully different story. You just need to get a list of file using standard Java IO (or NIO) API. you have polled file and based on this one you need to implement some simple service-activator (`.handle()`) to obtain other files based on the polled one.

Comment: Great. I thought so, but just wanted to check if there was other way inside of the SI API for that case. I've found that I can implement many things using `MessageHandlers` or `Transformers`; but in many cases SI has a proper API for those cases that's more feature-rich (and battle tested!), so I'm trying to avoid reimplementing the wheel. Marking as accepted!

Comment: That's correct, but for such a simple API like Java File IO, there is nothing to wrap to specific high level one. Frankly I often meet a question how to delete `java.io.File` in Spring Integration ;-)